# sed: extract lines until unmatched pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I am trying to extract lines from a file where the end string is different from the begin string

I have the following input file in format:

```
<item_id>6</item_id>
  <info1>abc</info1>
  <info2>123</info2>
<item_id>6</item_id>
  <info1>def</info1>
  <info2>456</info2>
<item_id>6</item_id>
  <info1>ghi</info1>
  <info2>789</info2>
<item_id>9</item_id> 
  <info1>jkl</info1>
  <info2>012</info2>
<item_id>9</item_id>
  <info1>mno</info1>
  <info2>345</info2>
```

I want to extract from "6" until "9" (9 being a random number)

Begin is `<item_id>6<\item_id>`

End is `<item_id>X<\item_id>` X being anything but 6

Expected result:

```
<item_id>6</item_id>
  <info1>abc</info1>
  <info2>123</info2>
<item_id>6</item_id>
  <info1>def</info1>
  <info2>456</info2>
<item_id>6</item_id>
  <info1>ghi</info1>
  <info2>789</info2>
```

I tried:

```
sed -n "/<item_id>6<\/item_id>/,/<item_id>!6<\/item_id>/p" input.file > output.6
sed -n "/<item_id>6<\/item_id>/,/<item_id>\!6<\/item_id>/p" input.file > output.6
sed -n "/<item_id>6<\/item_id>/,/<item_id>\{!6}<\/item_id>/p" input.file > output.6
sed -n "/<item_id>6<\/item_id>/,/<item_id>(6)\@!.<\/item_id>/p" input.file > output.6
sed -n "/<item_id>6<\/item_id>/,/<item_id>! 6<\/item_id>/p" input.file > output.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this GNU sed script will work for you:

```
sed '/<item_id>6<\/item_id>/{:1;n;/<item_id>[^6]<\/item_id>/{Q};b1};d' file
```

Keep deleting `d` lines until a `6` line is found, then keep in the internal loop `b1` printing each line until a `not 6` ([^6]) line is found, at which time the script is `Q`uit.

Understand that this works only for **one character** numbers (the `6` or the `9`).

---

It gets quite messy to get it to work with any number (GNU):

```
sed -e 'h;s,<item_id>\([0-9]*\)<\/item_id>,\1,;/^6$/!d;/^6$/{g;:1;h;s,<item_id>\([0-9]*\)<\/item_id>,\1,;t2;:3;g;n;b1};d;b;:2;/^6$/!Q;b3' file
```

Using a couple of vars makes it a bit better, but not that much

```
reg='<item_id>\([0-9]*\)<\/item_id>'
item='6'

sed -e "h;s,$reg,\1,;/^$item$/!d;/^$item$/{g;:1;h;s,$reg,\1,;t2;:3;g;n;b1};d;b;:2;/^$item$/!Q;b3" file
```

And a POSIXfyed one looks like gibberish:

```
sed -ne 'h;s,<item_id>\([0-9]*\)<\/item_id>,\1,;/^6$/!d;/^6$/{g;:1;h;s,<item_id>\([0-9]*\)<\/item_id>,\1,;t2;:3;g;p;n;b1;};d;b;:2;/^6$/!q;b3' file
```

Only this extended code might(?) be more readable:

```
reg='<item_id>\([0-9]*\)<\/item_id>'
item='6'

sed -ne 'h;                 # hold copy of line being processed.
         s,'"$reg"',\1,;    # extract included number.
         /^'"$item"'$/!d;   # Not the correct number?: get next line.
         /^'"$item"'$/{
         g;                 # restore line from hold buffer.
         :1
         h;                 # store successive lines in hold buffer.
         s,'"$reg"',\1,;    # extract the number (again).
         t2
         :3
         g;                 # restore the line back from hold buffer.
         p;                 # print the line.
         n;                 # go to process next line.
         b1
         };                 # end of loop.
         d;                 # avoid printing this last line.
         q;                 # quit the sed script.
         :2
         /^'"$item"'$/!q;   # Test if the number is the one selected.
         b3
        ' file
```

Maybe you should use some other language or tool.

Comment: This will not break out of the loop if the next item has two or three digits, only works with one digit items...

Comment: that's great. almost there. it does not work for a string <item_id>12 until <item_id>15 for example :(.. i tried a few things but cant get it

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Yes, that is what I said *one character numbers*. Anyway, a more flexible (but hard to read) solution added.

Comment: thanks! it makes it complicated indeed but this works perfectly. thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is a well-formed XML document, the following uses XMLStarlet to pick out the `info_id` nodes whose values are `6`, and then the immediately following sibling `info1` and `info2` nodes:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//item_id[. = 6]' \
    -c . -nl \
    -c './following-sibling::info1[1]' -nl \
    -c './following-sibling::info2[1]' -nl file.xml
<item_id>6</item_id>
<info1>abc</info1>
<info2>123</info2>
<item_id>6</item_id>
<info1>def</info1>
<info2>456</info2>
<item_id>6</item_id>
<info1>ghi</info1>
<info2>789</info2>
```

Alternatively, to ignore what the following nodes are called:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//item_id[. = 6]' \
    -c . -nl \
    -c './following-sibling::*[1]' -nl \
    -c './following-sibling::*[2]' -nl file.xml
```